# Start.Process() .net Core doesn't work in Linux Docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have created a docker container with a ASP.net Core Service. This service, however, should start another service inside the docker container. The problem I am facing right now is that Process.Start() doesn't seem to work in this Linux container.

This is what I tried so far:

```
            Process process;
            ProcessStartInfo processInfo;

            string fileName = "bin/bash dotnet run /root/SubService/SubService.API.dll";
            string arguments = $"Company --urls http://localhost:5000/SolutionName";
            string escapedArguments  = $"-c /{arguments}/";

            processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(escapedFilename, escapedArguments)
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                RedirectStandardError = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = false
            };

            try
            {
                process = Process.Start(processInfo);
                process.WaitForExit();
                process.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
```

When Process.Start(processInfo) is called I get the exception "No such file or directory". The path, however, is correct.
What could be the problem? Or is there an alternative way to start a process from a asp.net core service.

Thank you.

Comment: There is definitely something wrong with that filename parameter. Try running something else like command prompt or notepad and see if it is related to the filename parameter or about the rest of the c# program. Then if it is about the filename we can figure it out.

Comment: I tried with UseShellExecute as well, but that, unfortunately, didn't help.
I am pretty sure that the filename parameter is correct. How come you think otherwise @ÖzgürGüzeldereli?

Comment: Ok, it might not be wrong sorry. I thought about something else. Can you try to run something else other than bash with the Process.start? Anything other than your desired command. A text editor for example but with the same startInfo. If you can open something else with your process.start then the problem is with the filename/path/parameters

Comment: Will try, but might take some time.Thank you!

Comment: OK no problem take your time. When you finish, write me the output or result from here and I'll see what we can do next. BTW your code doesn't include the escapedFilename being defined.

Comment: @ÖzgürGüzeldereli I figured it out over some time, thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

After some more testing, the problem seemed to be the incorrect use of the Process.Start() method. This time arguments were used.

This is how it worked:

```
            Process process;
            string outputStream;
            string errorStream;

            try
            {
                string fileName = "dotnet";
                string arguments = $"{subServiceData.ApplicationPath} {subServiceData.SolutionName} --urls { subServiceData.SubServiceUrl}";
                process = Process.Start(fileName, arguments);
                process.WaitForExit();

                // *** Read the streams ***
                outputStream = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                errorStream = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

                int exitCode = process.ExitCode;
                process.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
```